# Find closest number C++ using arrays, floats

Tags: c++, average

I need to find the closest (and minor) number to the average in the given numbers. For example:

If the given numbers are 1,2,3,4,5 the average will be 3, and the closest numbers are 2 and 4 but the minor is 2 so the result should be 2.

Or, if the given numbers are 1, 325, 350, 299 the average will be 243.75 so the closest number is 299.

```
int best = a[0];
for (i = 1; i < count; ++i)
best = abs(a[i] - x) < abs(best - x) ? a[i] : best;
```

Comment: Are your arrays always sorted when performing this operation?

Comment: are the numbers always positive?

Answer (score 2):

Your code's almost right... you just need to also check if the distance from the average `x` is the *same* as best's distance, but on the minor side while `best` isn't....

```
double i_delta = abs(a[i] - x);
double x_delta = abs(best - x);
if (i_delta < x_delta)
     best = a[i];
else if (i_delta == x_delta && a[i] < best)
     best = a[i];
```

(You have to do one pass through the values to calculate the average, so your overall algo's going to be O(n).  So an extra iteration like you're using isn't reducing the overall big-O efficiency... all good.)

Answer (score -1):

This isn't tough and you should be able to do that. I'm assuming this is question from your school homework and you are not in mood

```
int closest(int* array, int size){
//Calculating sum for finding average first
    double sum = 0.0;
    for (int i=0; i< size; i++){
        sum+= array[i]*1.0;
    }
//Here is our average
    double average = sum/size;
//Assuming initial answer is very huge so that every other comparison is less than this
    int answer = 100000000;
    for (int i=0; i< size; i++){
//Finiding the difference for current element
        double temp = abs(array[i]-average);
        double temp1 = abs(answer - average);
//If current difference is less than previous one that replace the previous answer
        if (temp < temp1) answer = array[i];
//If they are equal then accept the minor one
        else if (temp == temp1){
            if (array[i]< answer) answer = array[i];
        }
    }

    return answer;
}
```

P.S. This isn't good practice to ask such question to ask here. You should have attempted it first and then posted your question with your attempt.

Comment: `int answer = 100000000;` Using arbitrary large values should be discouraged. If at all an upper bound is required, you should use `numeric_limits<int>::max()` instead. Besides, your answer is basically the same as the code in the question.

Comment: as seems from the examples values are quite small and `answer` is still is in limits of INT_MAX

Comment: It's just a matter of good practice. The value of INT_MAX is system dependent.